# Why does GeometryReader seem to give me wrong values?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using the code below I'm seeing a height of 647.0 in landscape and 375.0 in portrait on the 2nd generation iPhone SE simulator. Why do these values seem reversed?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let orientationDidChangeNotification =
        NotificationCenter
            .default
            .publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
    
    @State var height: CGFloat?
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            Color.clear
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .onReceive(orientationDidChangeNotification) { _ in
                    height = geometryProxy.size.height
                }
                .onChange(of: height) { newValue in
                    print("height", newValue ?? "nil")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but with your code, it is printing the incorrect values to the console. However, if you change your `Color.clear` to `Text(geometryProxy.size.height.description)`, the correct value will show on screen. I don't have time tonight to dig into why. What is your use case?

Comment: Works fine as-is. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Thanks, looks like a bug in iOS 16.0.

Answer (score 0):

As Asperi says, this does work as expected in Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5. It appears this is bug with iOS 16.0.